# HTML creating an onsubmit redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onsubmit

I am trying to redirect the user to a new page on the current website once the form is submitted to another url.

I've looked at so many boards to figure out the best way. I cannot modify the destination URL for posting so I was thinking that the onsubmit function would work best to redirect the user to another page. But for some reason I can't figure out how to get the redirect to work.

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
<form method=post onSubmit="window.location.href='https://thankyoupage.com/'action="https:       //urltopostto.com?encoding=UTF-8"><input type="hidden" name="inquiry_from" value="website" />
    <fieldset><legend style="display: inline !important;">We Can't Wait to Hear from You</legend>
    <div><label for="first_name">First Name*</label>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" maxlength="40" name="first_name" required="" size="20" /></div>

    <div><label for="last_name">Last Name*</label>
    <input id="last_name" type="text" maxlength="80" name="last_name" required="" size="20" /></div>

    <div><label for="email">Email*</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" size="20" /></div>

    <div><label for="phone">Phone*</label>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="(111) 111-1111" required="" size="20" /></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset><legend>Company Information</legend>

    <div><label for="company">Organization Name*</label>
    <input id="organization" type="text" maxlength="40" name="organization" required="" size="20" /></div>
    <div>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset>

<div><label for="Inquiry">Can you provide us additional information?</label>
<textarea id="inquiry" maxlength="&quot;256" name="inquiry" rows="6" wrap="soft"></textarea>       </div>
<section><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></section></fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but your onSubmit has an open double quote at the beginning, but no closing one at the end. It looks like action is being read as part of the onSubmit function.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are trying to redirect to another page (for example, "/page1"), when a user submits a form which will be posting the form data to a page (for example, "/page2"). Is this correct?

If you own the page2 meaning your server is serving up the page, then you can basically handle the redirect to page1 there.

However, if you don't own the page, you can use AJAX to post the form data to the page2 AND THEN redirect to page1 within your page using jQUery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit_button_for_the_form').click(function (e) {
    // Don't do the regular form POST
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get form variables...
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
    ...

    // Post the form variables to page2
    $.post('/page2', {
      first_name : first_name,
      last_name : last_name,
      ...
    });

    // redirect to page1
    window.location = '/page1';  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that I understand the question correctly. Wouldn't that be done rather easily, and better from the file you're posting to? (https://urltopostto.com)

You say you cannot modify the destination url. Does it mean that you cannot add anything to the destination file as well?

You could send the user directly to the thank you page and then submit the form data from behind the scenes. This would be a$$-backward and you'll have to be very careful to warn the user if things don't work (which would be some funky UX) but it would work.

There are many questions here. The best would be to do work with the file you're posting to.